# Prevent DDOS Attack on GCP App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ddos, google-app-engine, denial-of-service

I've launched my application on GCP App Engine with 8 micro-services.
I did an overload test with apache j-meter and it seems to scale well.

However this can also be used as a DOS attack on my application and app engine does not seem to be blocking any of the looping requests but instead, it keeps scaling up the servers (which is fine), but however I want to be able to prevent such DOS attacks on my application.

I checked the firewall documentation of GCP App Engine and in that, you can specify an IP to be blocked. But is there a way to automate this process and prevent such attacks without manually putting the IP in the firewall rules.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor), a service which helps protect your applications and websites against denial of service and web attacks. You may have a look at the [Best Practices for DDoS Protection and Mitigation
on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) document.

Comment: I checked this but it can't be configured to App Engine, it acts the same as the firewall feature on app engine.

Comment: Would you like to set up defenses against DDOS attacks other than by configuring a firewall? You may have a look at the [Best Practices for DDoS Protection and Mitigation
on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) document.